# Oauth 2.0 handler functions for Tornado

Tags: python, asynchronous, authentication, tornado

With Tornado 3.2 they made some updates to auth module and have updated the code. Earlier I was using open id for Google login, since it will be deprecated in the future I am switching the code to Oauth 2.0 login. Also I was using `tornado.web.asynchronous`, now I have updated the code to use `tornado.gen.coroutine`

`/products` is only available for logged in users. Once the user is authenticated from Google or Facebook, a cookie called 'trakr' is set. In implementation of `get_current_user()` whether 'trakr' is set or not is checked.

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get_current_user(self):
        user = self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
        if not user: return None
        return True

class FAuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        if self.get_argument('code', None):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(
                redirect_uri=settings.fb_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
                client_secret=self.settings['facebook_secret'],
                code=self.get_argument('code'))

            if not user:
                self.clear_all_cookies()
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Facebook authentication failed')

            user = yield self.facebook_request("/me", access_token=user["access_token"])

            if not user:
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, "Facebook authentication failed.")

            self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user.get('email'))
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        elif self.get_secure_cookie('trakr'):
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=settings.fb_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'], 
                extra_params={'scope': 'email'}
            )

class GAuthLoginHandler(BaseHandler, tornado.auth.GoogleOAuth2Mixin):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        if self.get_current_user():
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        if self.get_argument('code', False):
            user = yield self.get_authenticated_user(redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                code=self.get_argument('code'))
            if not user:
                self.clear_all_cookies() 
                raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Google authentication failed')

            access_token = str(user['access_token'])
            http_client = self.get_auth_http_client()
            response =  yield http_client.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token='+access_token)
            user = json.loads(response.body)

            self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email']) 
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        elif self.get_secure_cookie('trakr'):
            self.redirect('/products')
            return

        else:
            yield self.authorize_redirect(
                redirect_uri=settings.google_redirect_url,
                client_id=self.settings['google_oauth']['key'],
                scope=['email'],
                response_type='code',
                extra_params={'approval_prompt': 'auto'})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few small improvements I can see:

1. Your `get_current_user()` function is slightly misleading. Currently, you return `None` if there is no current user, or `True` if there is. This function isn't returning the current user, its returning **if there is** a current user.

   If I assume the return value of `get_secure_cookie()` is a basic string, the method can actually be reduced to this single line:

   ```
   # On a valid return, the return value will be a non-empty string == True.
   # Otherwise, it will either be None or '', both of which == False.
   return self.get_secure_cookie('trakr')
   ```

   Since, this function is just passes through of the return value of another function, it really isn't necessary. Unless you wanted to keep it to describe what the return value of `self.get_secure_cookie()` could mean, I would suggest removing it entirely.
2. In your `get()` functions you have this if structure:

   ```
   if get_current_user():
       self.redirect('/product')
       return
   ```

   followed by:

   ```
   if self.get_argument('code', None):
       ...
   elif self.get_secure_cookie('trackr'):
       self.redirect('/products')
       return
   ```

   First you check for a current user; if there is none you continue on. Then, if you get a `False` return value from `self.get_argument('code', None)`, you immediately check again. From what I can tell from your snippet, unless you expect a user to get logged in during the time it takes to evaluate two if statements, the second user check is redundant.
3. I would change your naming conventions a bit. The `G` and `F` at the beginnings of your classes can be understood when looking at the source code. However, away from the source the `F` and `G` can be ambiguous.

   I would recommend using the names: `FacebookLoginHandler` and `GoogleLoginHandler`.

   Also, instead of `trackr` I would use the full work `tracker`. Saving 1 character isn't worth it.
4. I would use `str.format()` instead of string concatenation. You only do this once and with only two strings. However, string formatting is more Pythonic and it, personally, describes better what the final string will look like:

   ```
   'Hello' + ' ' + 'world' + '!'   vs.   '{} {}!'.format('Hello', 'world')
   ```
5. My final point is more personal preference than a sure-fire Python convention. Whenever you have to split up a single statement onto multiple lines, you indent the next line 4 spaces in. As alluded to earlier, this fine:

   ```
   yield self.authorize_redirect(
       redirect_uri=settings.fb_redirect_url,
       client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'], 
       extra_params={'scope': 'email'}
   )
   ```

   > As a small aside, I don't like having the ending param on a line by itself; its too C/Java-like.

   However, my personal preference is to indent them to line up (or as close to in line) with the section of the statement they are related to. Take this 'simple' example:

   ```
   # Technically OK.
   some_long_variable_name = [foobar for foobar in map(ord, 'Hello World!')
       if foobar < 97]

   # My preference.
   some_long_variable_name = [foobar for foobar in map(ord, 'Hello World!')
                              if foobar < 97]
   ```

   In the first statement above, its slightly difficult to tell at a glance the if statement is in the list comprehension. Even though they are related syntactically, they currently aren't related spatially.

   Now in the second statement, the if statement and the rest of the comprehension are related spatially which, personally, helps the code make more sense at a glance.

   Here is how I would structure your code:

   ```
   yield self.authorize_redirect(redirect_uri=settings.fb_redirect_url,
                                 client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'], 
                                 extra_params={'scope': 'email'})
   ```

---

Otherwise, your code looks pretty good. I really wanted to look more into a single `Login` class because your two classes are so similar. However, a solution did not come quickly to mind and creating one would go past the bounds of typical code review.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much. There is a typo in your answer, instead of `get_source_cookie()` it should be `get_secure_cookie()`. Regarding #1, you are right. Actually I use a boilerplate tornado code which I created when I first started learning python and tornado. However I still need to have `get_current_user` function since it will be used in `@tornado.web.authenticated` decorator. And I agree rest of your points. Cheers!